# Xpath selecting Input Radio based on following text

Tags: html, xpath, siblings

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" class="inputs-highlight" name="country"><h2>Russia</h2>
<input type="radio" class="inputs-highlight" name="country"><h2>USA</h2>
<input type="radio" class="inputs-highlight" name="country"><h2>Other</h2>
```

I'm trying to select the input radio where the text is equal to "Other".

I tried with:

```
 .//input[./@type = 'radio']/following::*[text() = "Other"]
```

But this is returning the H2 element not the Input Radio element.

And with this:

```
 //input[@type='radio' and following-sibling::text() = 'Other']
```

there is no result.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the *first* occurrence:

```
//input[@type="radio"][following-sibling::*[1]/text()='Other']
```

since it is true that there exists an element containing `Other` *after* the selected `input`. The expression above selects only the inputs where the *next* sibling contains `Other`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @helderdarocha only works because the search text is in the "h2" tags. A more flexible solution, which doesn't care how the following text is "packed" would be:

```
//input[@type='radio'][following-sibling::node()[position() = 1 and normalize-space(.) = 'Other']]
```

With help from: http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/getting-a-checkbox-by-its-adjacent-text-node/

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can select any particular radio button like:

If you want to select Other Radio Button then:

```
//h2[text()="Other"]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

If you want to select USA Radio Button then:

```
//h2[text()="USA"]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

If you want to select Russia Radio Button then:

```
//h2[text()="Russia"]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

I hope it will solve your problem.